# How to disable a button within a mapped div for a period of time

Tags: reactjs

I have an array of objects, and by `.map()` method i am returning the objects' elements within the `divs`. There is this button that calls a function with 24hr cooldown, and i would like to disable the button for that period of time when it's clicked. Otherwise it throws me an error from the serverside (I'm using blockchain as the backend, and transactions throw error if the requirements aren't met). I can't use a `state` like `isButtonDisabled`, because i  just want a specific button to be disabled.

Here is the mapped `div` part of the code;

```
<div className="row" id="chars-row">
            <main role="main" className="col-lg-12 d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-center">  
                { characters.map( (chr, key) => {
                    return( 
                    <div className="col-md-2 card m-1" key={key} >
                        <img className="card-img-top chr_img" src= {(Math.max(chr.strength, chr.health, chr.dexterity, chr.intelligence, chr.magic) == chr.strength)
                                                                    ? require('../assets/str.png') 
                                                                    : (Math.max(chr.strength, chr.health, chr.dexterity, chr.intelligence, chr.magic) == chr.health)
                                                                    ? require('../assets/hp.png') 
                                                                    : (Math.max(chr.strength, chr.health, chr.dexterity, chr.intelligence, chr.magic) == chr.dexterity)
                                                                    ? require('../assets/dex.png') 
                                                                    : (Math.max(chr.strength, chr.health, chr.dexterity, chr.intelligence, chr.magic) == chr.intelligence)
                                                                    ? require('../assets/int.png') 
                                                                    : (Math.max(chr.strength, chr.health, chr.dexterity, chr.intelligence, chr.magic) == chr.magic)
                                                                    ? require('../assets/mgc.png')  : null }  alt=""/>
                        <div className="card-body">                                
                        <div> <b>Name:</b> <span>{(chr.name).replace(/['"]+/g, '')}</span></div>
                        <div> <b>ID:</b> <span>{key}</span></div>
                        <div> <b>STR:</b> <span>{chr.strength}</span></div>
                        <div> <b>HP:</b> <span >{chr.health}</span></div>
                        <div> <b>Dex:</b> <span>{chr.dexterity}</span></div>              
                        <div> <b>INT:</b> <span >{chr.intelligence}</span></div>  
                        <div> <b>MAGIC:</b> <span >{chr.magic}</span></div>   
                        <div> <b>LEVEL:</b> <span >{chr.level}</span></div>  
                        <div> <b>EXP:</b> <span >{chr.experience}</span> / 255</div>
                                            
                        <div className="progress">
                            <div className="progress-bar progress-bar-striped bg-info" role="progressbar" style={{'width': (chr.experience * 100 / 255) + '%'}} aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="255"></div>
                        </div> 
                        <a href={`https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/${ownerAccounts[key]}`} target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"><small className="text-secondary owner_address">{ownerAccounts[key]}</small></a>                           
                        </div>   
                        <button className="btn btn-danger my-1"  value={key} onClick={openModal(key)}>Battle!</button>  
                    </div>
                    )
                })}         
            </main>        
            </div>
```

Comment: How do you know that the button has been clicked before? Where is the data stored? Does the character have a "lastBattle" property?

Comment: you can use State to disable the button. you just need to make the button separate component

Comment: There is a `mapping` from tokenId to battle time, and a `require` within the function `(tokenIdToCooldown[attackerId] + 86400) < block.timestamp)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, thanks for the helps. I have solved my problem.

I could query my last battle epoch time for each member of the array from blockchain
(from `mapping(uint256 => uint256) public tokenIdToCooldown` ):

```
      useEffect(() => {
    const getLastBattle = async () => {        
      let temp = [];
      let totalChars = await contract.methods.getTotalCharacterNumber().call({ from: accounts });
      for(let i=0; i<totalChars; i++) {
        let lastBattle = await contract.methods.tokenIdToCooldown(i).call();
        temp[i] = lastBattle;
      } 
      setLastBattle(temp);
    }
    if(typeof web3 !== 'undefined' && typeof accounts !== 'undefined' && typeof contract !== 'undefined') {
      getLastBattle();          
    } 
  }, [accounts, web3, contract])
```

Then i have checked whether that time passes now (after adding 24hr in seconds), and assinged a bool value for each of them;

```
      useEffect(() => {
    const lastBattleBool = async () => {
      var now = Math.round(Date.now() / 1000);
      let totalChars = await contract.methods.getTotalCharacterNumber().call({ from: accounts });
      let temp = [];
      for(let i=0; i<totalChars; i++) {
        if((lastBattle[i] + 86400) < now) {
          temp[i] = true;
        } else {
          temp[i] = false;
        }
        setBoolBattle(temp);
      }
    }
    if(typeof web3 !== 'undefined' && typeof accounts !== 'undefined' && typeof contract !== 'undefined') {
      lastBattleBool();          
    }         
  }, [lastBattle, accounts, web3, contract]);
```

My last approach was checking that bool value before displaying the button;

```
{boolBattle[characterCountOfOwner[key]] 
 ? <button className="btn btn-danger my-1" value={characterCountOfOwner[key]} 
 onClick={battle(characterCountOfOwner[key])}>Battle!</button> 
 : null}
```

Answer (score 0):

These are just snippets. But the idea is working. This will make the clicked button disabled.

Parent

```
const Parent = () => {
    const data = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
    return (
        <div>
        {data.map((data) => (
            <Child/>
        ))
        }
        </div>
    )
}
```

Child

```
const Child = ({data}) => {
    const [disable, setDisable] = useState(false);
    return (
        <div onPress={ () => setDisable(true)}>
            {data}
        </div>
    )
}

export default Child
```